# Consume Twitter Data without Permission through API

Tags: c#, api, twitter, oauth

Is it possible to access Twitter account information without their consent through API?

For example, if i have an app that is authorized by a single person (if their account is private); and I obtain a list of their followers.

Now, if i need to go through the tweets of their followers; do i need to get permission from each of their followers or should I be able to consume their tweets (if they are public of course) without any permission issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need permission from the individual users.

If you, as a Twitter user, can see a person's tweets then you can see their user information.